# Working with Multiple Views in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, multiview

I'm doing some tutorials on iPhone development and I am working with window based applications to create an app with multiple views (The tutorial I'm using is from TheNewBoston 21-26). I'm currently using Xcode 4 to make these apps but I'm having trouble because Bucky uses Xcode 3 and there seem to be some differences. Every time I try to make this app, I end up with a blank white screen. I follow the instructions correctly watched the videos multiple times but still nothing happens. Even when I make my own simple window based application it does not seem to work. I think it may have something to do with connecting the views with the MainWindow. If you have somehow gotten this to work using only the instructions from the video can you please give me a link to a website or video that has a simple multi-view tutorial. If Xcode 4 no longer allows this method of working than can you please explain how to get around it. Thanks so much, I really appreciate you helping me. I know I'm new and this is a really basic question but it has been giving me a hard time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to iOS development! :) I haven't worked the specific tutorial which you mention, but there's certainly many many others around the web which you could refer to.

Here's just a couple off Google when I looked around a bit regarding handling multiple views through a NavigationController which look detailed enough with good guidelines;

- http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-transitioning-between-views/
- http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/

If you're totally new, I would totally recommend getting your hands on some iOS development book (its worth the investment!); there are many; and they outline the process in  good detail from start to finish. If you're unfamiliar with the whole process, there are many minor things that can go wrong and create frustration.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for responding! You are right, I should get a book. And the tutorials you linked are great. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're quite welcome Joe :) This is the book I've used, its a bit old now, but still very good > http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430216263. If the answer helped you out, would appreciate a vote up for it, or marking this as answered. Thanks!